# Does ReplaySubject.next(value) violate immutable state principle of redux store?

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs5, redux-observable

I have an Angular2 app that fetches data from a source that requires authentication, so the app component init event initiates the auth token fetch like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgRedux } from '@angular-redux/store';
import { rootReducer } from './app.reducer';
import * as createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import { AppActions } from './app.actions';
import { createEpicMiddleware, combineEpics } from 'redux-observable';
import { UserEpics } from './users/user.epics';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs/ReplaySubject';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private ngRedux: NgRedux<any>,
    private actions: AppActions,
    private userEpics: UserEpics,
  ) {
    ngRedux.configureStore(
      rootReducer,
      { user: { auth: { token$: new ReplaySubject(1) } } },
      [
        createLogger(),
        createEpicMiddleware(combineEpics(...userEpics.epics)),
      ]);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.ngRedux.dispatch(this.actions.getAuthToken());
  }
}
```

Redux is storing an Rxjs5 ReplaySubject, and this subject will be fed the token value from the reducer like this:

```
case AppActions.GET_AUTH_TOKEN_DONE:
  user.auth.token$.next(action.token);
  return Object.assign({}, user, {
    auth: {
      isFetching: false,
      token$: user.auth.token$,
      reason: undefined
    }
 });
```

This code is working for me, but does it violate the immutable state principle of the redux store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it does - since you can mutate the state from anywhere by calling `.next(...)` - if it was an `Observable` instead of a `Subject` it might be a little different - but in any case I personally think it'd be a bad practice to store `Observables` as part of the state.

Comment: Indeed this is highly discouraged. Everything in your store should be serializable, even if you do not actually ever serialize it. You don't have to be religious about it--if it contains something on accident that isn't ever used--but relying on it is bad form. All of that said, if there's no easy clear path to righteousness, ship it, but don't make a habit of it. At least that's my opinion. To provide you with a cleaner solution I'd need to see why you feel you need the Subject to behind with. e.g. your epic code. It seems like you could just set token in the store as-is without a subject?

Comment: @jayphelps Thanks, I suspected as much. I did this temporarily to satisfy a component that depends on the auth token in order to fetch view data. I re-factored this to a scheme where the component route is guarded by a subscription to the store's auth token, using [@angular-redux/store](https://github.com/angular-redux/store/blob/master/docs/select-pattern.md)